# Using Eval() with DAO.Recordset - Possible?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using a DAO.recordset (called rs2) based on an SQL query (in MS Access).  Calling the individual attributes in the recordset works just fine, as follows:

```
strName = rs2!Name
strDescr = rs2!Descr
```

I am trying to come up with a more generic way reference the attributes via a variable, without success, using the Eval() function.

Is something like this even possible?

```
strAttr = "Name"
strResult = Eval("rs2!" & strAttr)
```

Any suggestions to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Eval()` is evaluated by the Access expression service.  And that service doesn't have any awareness of VBA variables, including object variables such as your `rs2` recordset.

But I don't think you need something like `Eval()` to get what you want.  Use `strAttr` to reference that named field in the recordset's `.Fields` collection.

```vb
strAttr = "Name"
strResult = rs2.Fields(strAttr).Value
```